# Trigger Jenkins build for new pushed branch from GitLab CI

Tags: jenkins, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, jenkins-cli

I'm trying to trigger a Jenkins build from the GitLab CI using the following `bash` script.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

BRANCH=$1

if [ -z "${BRANCH}" ]; then
  BRANCH=$(git branch --show-current)
fi

JENKINS_CLI=jenkins-cli.jar
if [ ! -f "$JENKINS_CLI" ]; then
  echo "$JENKINS_CLI does not exist. Downloading from Jenkins ..."
  wget http://jenkins.lan:8080/jenkins/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar
fi

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://jenkins.lan:8080/ build -c PROJECT/"$(jq -R -r @uri <<<"$BRANCH")"
```

This works for branches that are already in Jenkins. If the branch is not in Jenkins, because it is fresh pushed, I get the error.:

```bash
$ ./trigger-jenkins-build.sh $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH
jenkins-cli.jar does not exist. Downloading from Jenkins ...
Connecting to jenkins.lan:8080
saving to 'jenkins-cli.jar'
jenkins-cli.jar      100% |********************************| 3487k  0:00:00 ETA
'jenkins-cli.jar' saved
ERROR: No such job 'PROJECT/feature%2FVW-9876_gitlab_ci_trigger_jenkins'; perhaps you meant 'PROJECT/feature%2FVW-6666_SOME_EXISTING_BRANCH_IN_JENKINS'?
Cleaning up project directory and file based variables 00:01
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

How can I create the build for the new branch using the jenkins-cli?